# Does NTFS alternate data stream become orphaned upon parent deletion?

Tags: windows, ntfs

What happens if you save a resource or something similar in the alternate data stream for a file, and that file is deleted:

If you try to access the stream again it will be empty in any of these cases, but since the original files in the alternate stream were not formally deleted do they just take up space forever or are they just treated as if they had been deleted / unlinked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The original question asked about what happens to alternate data streams when the file is moved.*

The alternate data streams are associated with the file. If you move the file, the alternate data streams move with the file.

Of course, if you move the file to a drive that does not support alternate data streams, then they are simply lost.

---

*But the question now is somewhat different, and asks about what happens when the file is deleted.*

Again, the alternate data streams are associated with the file. When the file is deleted, so too are all alternate data streams associated with the file.

Comment: They don't though, at least not across drives.

Comment: Maybe I moved it onto a non NTFS drive on accident

Comment: Well, obviously, if you move to a non NTFS drive, they just disappear.

Comment: I guess the main thing is that they are unlinked when the parent is deleted right?

Comment: They are part of the file. If you delete the file, then all alternate data streams will be removed.

Comment: I'm pretty unhappy about your question edit. My answer now looks stupid!

Comment: Ok, this is really what I wanted to know.  Cannot find very formal documentation for this, do you have a link to MSDN docs on this subject?  Sorry about the edit, I realized that my real question was making sure that they wouldn't be orphaned upon deletion, original question was bad.

Comment: You can infer what happens from this text in the docs: *When delete access is requested on a file, the operating system checks for delete access on all open streams in a file. If another process has opened a stream without the FILE_SHARE_DELETE permission, you cannot open the file for delete access.*  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404.aspx

Comment: Another time, if you've already got an answer to your question, instead of changing the question it might be best to ask your revised question as an addition to the question. That would make the original answer still valid. For instance, if I had never returned, I might not have noticed that the question had changed. Anyway, I think you now know what you want to know.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Excellent answer! Just as an additional input, here a few slides about ADS http://www.winitor.com/pdf/NtfsAlternateDataStreams.pdf